# how to highlight every pixel with a gradient between 22.5 and 67.5 degrees performing a Canny Edge detection?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have Implemented a Canny Edge detector using “Church Canny Edge” image as below. now I want to extend/modify my code in order to colour every pixel with a gradient between 22.5 and 67.5 degrees in the same image.

can you please give me lines of codes need be added to my current implementation?

```
                        << EDITION 1 >>
```

this is the version after editing it by help of Miki. when I build it , I get a black window which means somehow I am messing the image show part of code. any tips ?

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
Mat image, im_gray;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    /// Load an image
if(argc > 1)
    image = imread(argv[1]);    
else
    image = imread("Church Canny Edge.png");

/// Create a window
  namedWindow( "window");

if(image.empty())
cout << "Output sentence";
   // Mat3b img = imread("Church Canny Edge.png");

    Mat1b im_gray;
    cvtColor(image, im_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Mat1b detected_edges;
    GaussianBlur(im_gray, detected_edges, Size(3, 3), 0, 0);

    int lowThreshold = 200;
    int ratio = 3;
    int kernel_size = 3;

    Canny(detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold,
        lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size);


    // Compute Sobel derivatives
    Mat1f sx, sy;
    Sobel(detected_edges, sx, CV_32F, 1, 0, kernel_size);
    Sobel(detected_edges, sy, CV_32F, 0, 1, kernel_size);

    // Compute edge angle
    Mat1f angles(detected_edges.rows, detected_edges.cols, 0.f);

    for (int r = 0; r < detected_edges.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < detected_edges.cols; ++c)
        {
            angles(r, c) = atan2(sy(r, c), sx(r,c));
        }
    }

    // Convert radians to degrees
    angles = (angles / CV_PI * 180.0);

    // Get values in range
    Mat1b maskPositive;
    inRange(angles, Scalar(22.5), Scalar(67.5), maskPositive);
    Mat1b maskNegative;
    inRange(angles, Scalar(-67.5), Scalar(-22.5), maskNegative);
    Mat1b mask = maskNegative | maskPositive;

    // Show results
    Mat3b result;
    cvtColor(detected_edges, result, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    for (int r = 0; r < detected_edges.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < detected_edges.cols; ++c)
        {
            if (mask(r, c) && detected_edges(r, c))
            {
                result(r, c) = Vec3b(0,255,0);
            }
        }
    }

waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: can you use also a reference image to what effect you want to achieve? I don't know what is canny edge, but I can probably implement that If I see a result image

Comment: @DarioOO no need to reimplement Canny (it's a edge detector, btw :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the gradient angle using `Sobel` derivatives:

```
    // Compute Sobel derivatives
    Mat1f sx, sy;
    Sobel(detected_edges, sx, CV_32F, 1, 0, kernel_size);
    Sobel(detected_edges, sy, CV_32F, 0, 1, kernel_size);

    // Compute edge angle
    Mat1f angles(detected_edges.rows, detected_edges.cols, 0.f);

    for (int r = 0; r < detected_edges.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < detected_edges.cols; ++c)
        {
            angles(r, c) = atan2(sy(r, c), sx(r,c));
        }
    }

    // Convert radians to degrees
    angles = (angles / CV_PI * 180.0);
```

Angles:

[image]

Then you can keep only values in a specified range:

```
    // Get values in range
    Mat1b maskPositive;
    inRange(angles, Scalar(22.5), Scalar(67.5), maskPositive);
    Mat1b maskNegative;
    inRange(angles, Scalar(-67.5), Scalar(-22.5), maskNegative);
    Mat1b mask = maskNegative | maskPositive;
```

You can then color pixels that are both in mask and in canny edges:

```
    // Show results
    Mat3b result;
    cvtColor(detected_edges, result, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    for (int r = 0; r < detected_edges.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < detected_edges.cols; ++c)
        {
            if (mask(r, c) && detected_edges(r, c))
            {
                result(r, c) = Vec3b(0,255,0); // green
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

**NOTES**

- You probably don't want to draw pixels with a given gradient, but extract lines and draw lines with a given slope. You can do this using Hough Transform (available in OpenCV). I won't show this since it's not what was asked here.
- You can basically copy this code into your `CannyThreshold` function

Full code for reference:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat1b im_gray;
    cvtColor(img, im_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Mat1b detected_edges;
    GaussianBlur(im_gray, detected_edges, Size(3, 3), 0, 0);

    int lowThreshold = 200;
    int ratio = 3;
    int kernel_size = 3;

    Canny(detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold,
        lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size);


    // Compute Sobel derivatives
    Mat1f sx, sy;
    Sobel(detected_edges, sx, CV_32F, 1, 0, kernel_size);
    Sobel(detected_edges, sy, CV_32F, 0, 1, kernel_size);

    // Compute edge angle
    Mat1f angles(detected_edges.rows, detected_edges.cols, 0.f);

    for (int r = 0; r < detected_edges.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < detected_edges.cols; ++c)
        {
            angles(r, c) = atan2(sy(r, c), sx(r,c));
        }
    }

    // Convert radians to degrees
    angles = (angles / CV_PI * 180.0);

    // Get values in range
    Mat1b maskPositive;
    inRange(angles, Scalar(22.5), Scalar(67.5), maskPositive);
    Mat1b maskNegative;
    inRange(angles, Scalar(-67.5), Scalar(-22.5), maskNegative);
    Mat1b mask = maskNegative | maskPositive;

    // Show results
    Mat3b result;
    cvtColor(detected_edges, result, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    for (int r = 0; r < detected_edges.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < detected_edges.cols; ++c)
        {
            if (mask(r, c) && detected_edges(r, c))
            {
                result(r, c) = Vec3b(0,255,0);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To boost the performance a little bit when computing `angles`, I'd suggest that you parallelize it using [OpenMP](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#SolutionInOpenmp%203%200): just add `#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)` before `for (int r = 0; r < detected_edges.rows; ++r)`. Compile with `-fopenmp` (gcc/clang) ;) (it would have been nice to have a `cv::atan2()` function though...)

Comment: This question is not about performance, and such kind of optimization is not required in a toy program such this one (there is room for a lot of optimization here). In general, yes, you can optimize a lot of code (with or without OpenMP). but _first make it work, then make it work faster (if needed)_. Thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I built it , but it shows me a black window. I know that this must be just a silly mistake in my code lines order. I would appreciate your tip to solve this.

Comment: @Baron Probably you just need `result` to be global, the rest should work as is. But It's just a guess, since I can't see your updated code. You can test my code alone and see if it works for you

Comment: @Baron just add `imshow("window", result); before last `waitKey()`

Comment: @Baron glad it worked! If this answer your question, consider marking as the answer and upvoting